# How many ways can $5$ marbles be placed in $7$ boxes?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations

How many ways can $5$ marbles can be placed $7$ boxes if

(1)Marbles are different colors and marbles may share a box.

(2)Marbles are different colors and marbles may not share a box.

(3)Marbles are same color and marbles may not share a box.

(4)Marbles are same color and marbles may share a box.

My try:(1)$7^5$ (2)$7P2$ (3)? and (4)? plz Help.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

For 3, note that you simply need to choose 5 boxes out of the seven to put marbles in...

For 4, try using stars and bars, by thinking about the boxes as dividing lines between marbles. For example, the below arrangement would represent 2 marbles in box 1, none in box 2, 1 marble in box 3, none in box 4 and 5, and 1 marble in boxes 6 and 7. How many such arrangements are there?

```
**||*|||*|*
```

Answer (score 1):

> How many ways can $5$ marbles be placed in $7$ boxes if the marbles are different colors and marbles may share a box?

Your answer of $7^5$ is correct since there are seven choices for each of the five marbles.

> How many ways can $5$ marbles be placed in $7$ boxes if the marbles are different colors and marbles may not share a box?

Line up the marbles in some order.  Since the marbles may not share a box, we have seven choices for the first marble, six choices for the second marble, five choices for the third marble, four choices for the fourth marble, and three choices for the fifth marble.  Hence, the number of ways the marbles can be distributed is 
$$7 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 = \frac{7!}{2!} = \frac{7!}{(7 - 5)!} = P(7, 5)$$
not 
$$P(7, 2) = \frac{7!}{(7 - 2)!} = \frac{7!}{5!} = 7 \cdot 6$$

> How many ways can $5$ marbles be placed in $7$ boxes if the marbles are the same color and may not share a box?

We must select five of the seven boxes in which to place the marbles, which can be done in

> $$\binom{7}{5}$$

ways.

> How many ways can $5$ marbles be placed in $7$ boxes if the marbles are the same color and may share a box?

Let $x_k$, $1 \leq k \leq 7$, be the number of marbles placed in the $k$th box.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 + x_7 = 5$$
which is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of six addition signs in a row of seven ones.  For instance, 
$$1 + + 1 1 1 + 1 + + +$$
corresponds to $x_1 = 1$, $x_2 = 0$, $x_3 = 3$, $x_4 = 1$, $x_5 = x_6 = x_7 = 0$, while 
$$+ 1 + 1 + + 1 + 1 + 1$$
corresponds to $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 0$, $x_5 = x_6 = x_7 = 1$.  Thus, the number of ways we can distribute the marbles is the number of ways we can insert six addition signs in a row of five ones, which is

> $$\binom{5 + 6}{6} = \binom{11}{6}$$ since we must select which six of the eleven positions (five ones and six addition signs) will be filled with addition signs.